# show Visual form builder in the front end

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, templates, include

Iam anew in wordpress . i used this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/ to build custom pages then i tried to build a custom page called formbuilder.php to use it in the front end page .And in this page i tried to render the form builder creation page but nothing renderd .

```
                <?php // require 'wp-includes/formatting.php'; ?>

                <?php require 'wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php'; ?>
                <?php require 'wp-admin/includes/post.php'; ?>    

                <?php require_once('wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' ); ?>
                <?php require 'wp-admin/includes/template.php'; ?>
                <?php require 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php'; ?>
                <?php require 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php'; ?>
                <?php $visual_form_builder->css() ?>
                <?php $visual_form_builder->scripts() ?>
                <?php $visual_form_builder->includes() ?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->add_admin(); ?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->dashboard_widget(); ?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->dashboard_widget_control(); ?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->meta_box_form_items(); ?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->ajax_media_button(); ?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->meta_box_display_forms(); ?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->add_dashboard_widget()?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->add_meta_boxes(); ?>
                <?php // $visual_form_builder->admin_add_new(); ?>
```

Could you please helping me with ana easy way to render the admin page in the custom page template .

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish but `require`ing particular Core files is a red flag. Please explain the problem better. Also, PHP start and end tags ___are not "line start" and "line end" markers___!

Comment: sorry about this .my problem is how to show the admin page [visual form builder] in Front end .

Comment: You really should not be trying to include pieces of backend code on the front end. That code assumes certain things about security that won't necessarily be present if you only include parts of the backend, not to mention the high probability of "undefined function" errors. Build a new interface if you need to show something on the front.

Comment: Aha . if ican do this just give user role permission to acess this page . But in this case i want to customize the backend page to add my own menus And replace the top header . What's your opinion .

Comment: I would lean toward creating/altering a backend page but it is still not clear exactly what you are trying to do.